# destroy window with after python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I destroy a window that includes Clock class after a couple of seconds but Clock class has
`after_id = self.timeLbl2.after(200, self.tick2)` line and after the destroying process it gaves an error like:

> invalid command name "2247622112648tick2"
> while executing "2247622112648tick2"
> ("after" script)

What should i do to get rid of it?
I've tried   `after_cancel(after_id)` but it doesn't help.

Comment: In order for us to provide help we need a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Add the code snippet that's throwing your error then someone can help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.